# Specifying maps from horn to a simplicial set

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff

In the proof of "Joyal's coherence lemma" (lemma 1.6.2 from Cisinski's "Higher categories and homotopical algebra", one can find the following argument :

We have managed to specify three maps $y_i:\Delta^2\to X$, $i=0,1,3$, where $X$ is a simplicial set. Also, each of these maps fits in a commutative triangle that translates the commutativity of a triangle of maps in $X$ i.e. elements of $X_1$. Now comes the part I don't quite understand : the data of $y_0,y_1,y_3$ defines a morphism of $\Lambda_2^3\to X$. Why is that ? At first I assumed I had missed somewhere some property of $\Lambda_k^n$ like an isomorphism $Hom_{sSet}(\Lambda_k^n,X)\simeq ?$ where $?$ would be replaced by something appropriate like $\coprod Hom_{sSet}(...,...)$ or something, but I haven't found any such property in the book nor anywhere else in the literature. I assume this is routine to people familiar and comfortable with simplicial sets, but I am neither of those things so I'm having trouble seeing this. So is there a universal property like I thought there might be ? And how does one go from a triplets of $2$-simplices in $X$ to a map from $\Lambda_2^3$ ?

The horn is defined in Cisinski's book as $\Lambda_k^n:= \cup_{k\in E\subsetneq [n]}\Delta^E$ where $E$ is meant to be a totally ordered set, and $\Delta^E:=N(E)$ the nerve of the poset category, hence $\Delta^E\simeq \Delta^m$ for $m$ the cardinal of $ E$. Given that $Hom$ commutes with limits/colimits I assume that there indeed is such a universal property but I can't quite put my finger on it, partly because I don't really understand the index set the union is over in the definition of the horn.

Comment: First, do you understand what $\Lambda^2_1$ looks like? Can you draw it? $\Lambda^3_2$ is basically the same thing one dimension higher. If you have difficulty visualising it, try cutting some pieces of paper and gluing them together.

Comment: @ZhenLin Right so $\Lambda_1^2$ is something that looks like $\bullet\to\bullet\to\bullet$ i.e. take a triangle, remove the interior and a vertex. So I suppose $\Lambda_2^3$ can be pictured as a tetrahedron, minus the interior and a face which is precisely 3 copies of $\Delta^2$ glued together, i.e. an empty tetrahedron with no base... So I suppose I see why three maps $\Delta^2\to X$  with some coherence condition gives a map from $\Lambda_2^3$. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required universal property that you are missing is the colimit description of the simplicial horn (when $n\ge2$); $$\Lambda_k^n=\mathrm{coeq}\left(\bigsqcup_{0\le i<j\le n\\i,j\neq k}\Delta^{n-2}\overset{\langle\iota_i\circ\delta_{j-1}\rangle}{\underset{\underset{\langle\iota_j\circ\delta_i\rangle}{\longrightarrow}}{\longrightarrow}}\bigsqcup_{0\le m\le n\\m\neq k}\Delta^{n-1}\right)$$There is a similar presentation of the simplicial boundary for $n\ge2$; $$\partial\Delta^n\cong\mathrm{coeq}\left(\bigsqcup_{0\le i<j\le n}\Delta^{n-2}\overset{\langle\iota_i\circ\delta_{j-1}\rangle}{\underset{\underset{\langle\iota_j\circ\delta_i\rangle}{\longrightarrow}}{\longrightarrow}}\bigsqcup_{0\le m\le n}\Delta^{n-1}\right)$$

In both cases cocone presenting either object as that colimit is given by $\langle\delta_m\rangle$. This is focussed e.g. in Goerss/Jardine’s “Simplicial Homotopy Theory”. It is a good (tedious) exercise to check these.

The upshot is that to specify a map out of the horn $\Lambda^3_2$, the universal property of a coequaliser tells me I only need to find three maps $a,b,c:\Delta^2\to X$ satisfying $c\delta_1=b\delta_2,c\delta_0=a\delta_2,b\delta_0=a\delta_0$ ie we need only present three $2$-simplices such that $d_1c=d_2b, d_0c=d_2a$ and $d_0b=d_0a$. In the textbook I mention, the authors almost always describe morphisms from the horn by such tuples, e.g. they would write $(a,b,-,c)$ here, and this uniquely describes a map. However one must always be careful to ensure the intersection relations hold on the $a,b,c$ ($d,e,f,g,…$) to make this rigorous.